# Unable to upload files on git repository

Tags: git, github

I have already created a git repo to upload my current project files and folder,
But it I'am not able to upload new files over.
Though I do not get any errors or warnings, but whenever I refresh my git repo it shows no changes.

when on-
git push  -u origin master
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

after refreshing the git page everything is same.
Basically I just want to add my node files and folders (contains js and json files). 
my repo -> https://github.com/Vishal-Kank/DevConnector

Comment: what does git status display?

Comment: are you adding your files to the staging area? `git add .` - adds all files, `git commit -m "my commit message"`

Answer (score 2):

Follow these commands from start (delete previous .git)
**Step 1**: open git bash and type git .init (this initializes empty git folder)
**Step 2**: git remote add origin  https://.....   (copy the http url of your repo)

**Step 3**: git add . (this adds all the changed file for commit)

**Step 4**: git commit -m "first commit" (commit command ,commits the code locally)

**Step 5**: git push origin master(this will push the code to server(github))
**Step 6**: git status (check the status)

This will push the code to master branch. If you want to push in different branch than master then change branch before pushing add the command git checkout -b branch-name

For refernce:https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/basic-git-commands-776639767.html

Comment: That's not the correct use of blockquote. Adding, the person want to push local working directory to github. Git clone isn't required. `git remote add origin <url>` is the command to add remote on local working directory

Comment: will keep in mind next time.For sure thanks. @SagarV and, he said he has already created repo..so cloning it to local then again pushing the files

Comment: You need `git remote add` rather than git clone

Answer (score 1):

You might need to `git add ./file/path` so it's actually added to the index. When you create new files or directories, git doesn't track them until you `add` them to the index. Short solution:

```
git add . 
git commit -m 'some message here'
git push origin master
```

Add all files, commit all added files with a message, push to remote master.

Side bar: the `-u` option on git push sets the upstream repository, you don't have to do that every time.